Show that $\mathcal{A}n$ is generated under colimits by its terminal object
In a course on $\infty$-categories I am attending we were asked to show that $\mathcal{A}n$ (by which I mean the $\infty$-category of anima which we defined as the simplicial nerve of the subcategory kan complexes in simplicial sets) is generated under colimits by its terminal object. However I dont know what it means to be generated under colimits by a terminal object (also not in 1-categories). Could somebody explain to me what I have to show?

There are essentially two ''levels'' at which you can interpret this statement.

(The easier one.) For any $X\in\mathrm{An}$, there is a diagram $F\colon\mathcal{I}\to\mathrm{An}, i\mapsto *$ with $\mathrm{colim}\,F\simeq X$. In other words, any object can in a way be written as a colimit of a functor that is constant at $*\in\mathrm{An}$, but you can pick the domain $\mathcal{I}$ of $F$ as you want.
(The cooler but harder one.) Given two cocomplete $\infty$-categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$, write $\mathrm{Fun}^\mathrm{cocont}(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D})$ for the full subcategory of $\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D})$ on the functors that preserve all colimits. Then for any cocomplete $\infty$-category $\mathcal{D}$, the evaluation functor
$$
\mathrm{ev}_*\colon\mathrm{Fun}^\mathrm{cocont}(\mathrm{An},\mathcal{D})\to\mathcal{D},\,F\mapsto F(*)
$$
is an equivalence of $\infty$-categories.

Statement 2. says that $\mathrm{An}$ is freely generated under colimits by $*\in\mathrm{An}$, and statement 1. just says it is generated under colimits by it. Another way to phrase statement 1. is as follows: we can write $\mathcal{C}$ for the full subcategory of $\mathrm{An}$ on  the objects that are colimits of constant functors on $*$. Then statement 1. is equivalent to saying that the inclusion $\mathcal{C}\to\mathrm{An}$ is an equivalence of $\infty$-categories.
If you have not covered Kan extensions yet, your course is asking you to show statement 1. If you have covered Kan extensions already, you may enjoy trying to prove 2., but your course is still only asking you to show 1.
